# How to train a neural network to identify if a written and spoken number are the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

The data provided contains a dataset of written numbers (45000 rows, 784 columns), a dataset of spoken numbers (45000 rows, 1 column) and a dataset containing labels with values TRUE or FALSE (45000, boolean). The label-value is TRUE when the spoken and written value are corresponding to the same number. Therefore, I need to create a neural network to predict if the outcome would be TRUE or FALSE.

Firstly, I summarized the data (min, max, mean, std dev) and applied a Perceptron but the error rate was too high. So now I'm trying to create a neural network to apply to this problem. But I'm getting stuck.

First I reshaped the data to get it to work:

```
written_train = written_train.reshape(45000,28,28)
spoken_train = spoken_train.reshape(45000,1,1)
```

After that I wanted to apply this model to the data:

```
def model(i,p,data_a,data_b,labels):
    x=Input(shape=(28,28))
    y=Input(shape=(1,1))
    admi=LSTM(40,return_sequences=False)(x)
    pla=LSTM(40,return_sequences=False)(y)
    out=concatenate([admi,pla],axis=-1)
    print(pla)
    print(out)
    output=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)
    model = Model(inputs=[x, y], outputs=output)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
    n=model.fit([data_a, data_b],labels,batch_size=1, epochs=10)
    return n

re=model(1,4,written_train,spoken_train,match_train)
print(re)
```

This results in the following error message:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So I do think there is some pre-processing needed but I don't know how and what to do. 
Also, this is my first time on Stackoverflow. So if there's anything I need to improve, please let me know :)

Comment: Hi Evi, `spoken_train = spoken_train.reshape(45000,1,1)`.   It would make a bit more sense if dim 1 was 784, as in the indicated example width.  Maybe you should start by revisiting some of the simpler examples of image/audio classifications.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake in my questioning. It makes more sense now.

Comment: What kind of spoken data is this that? It seems strange to me that it only has a single column (i.e. one value per row).

Comment: Each recording is of variable length, and thus each example is given as an array of shape (N, 13), where N is the number of frames in the recording, and 13 the number of MFCC features.